# Is there Sublime Text - style command palette in Emacs?

Tags: completion, commands

There is such feature as Command Palette in Sublime text:
[image: Command Palette]

It provides searchable list of command with human-readable descriptions.

Is there anything similar to this in Emacs?

Comment: If you start typing after `M-x` sequence it will try to autocomplete (by pressing `TAB`) you'll get some matching options. The kind of search you have in the image would be very inefficient in Emacs due to very large number of available functions. Regardless, you could try `M-x apropos` or `M-x info-apropos`, or search the output of `C-h b` or if you are looking for a function (command): `C-h f` and try to autocomplete.

Answer (score 7):

I use `helm-M-x`. It's part of the package `helm`.
You can view a command's description with `helm-execute-persistent-action`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) provides what you describe.

And not only for `M-x` but for anything that prompts for a command name.

And it provides the same thing for not just names of commands but everything else: faces, buffers, files, variables, functions, bookmarks -- you name it.  It even provides completion of [key sequences and menus/menu items](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion).

And you can get [additional information](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_A_Propos_d'Apropos) (complete doc string) about any completion candidates, on demand.  And even without asking for complete doc on a candidate, you get a summary description of it in the mode line.

And you can [progressively narrow](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion) the set of candidates by using multiple patterns to match

Answer (score 3):

You can also try `counsel-M-x` which comes with [counsel](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper) package and uses `ivy`(similar to `helm`) as a backend.

If you are on emacs 25, there is the command `describe-symbol` which can provide help for any face/variable/function and `ivy` provides narrowing for that as well.